# Is there a way in cloud foundry cf push command to have a manifest.yml with several "profiles"?

Tags: manifest, cloud-foundry

We have different setups (deployment parameters) for prod and for non prod environments, in regards to memory, instances etc.

We are deploying our applications with Jenkins pipeline, on Pivotal Cloud Foundry environments, which is eventually calling a script with a "CF push" command.

We are examining using two different `manifest.yml` files (but dislike the duplicity if identical parameters).
We are also examining using `--var-file` with two different vars files. We have a concern with backward compatibility, and the effort (we have many MSs) of adding so many files.

We want a `manifest.yml` that will look like this:

```yaml
applications:
- name: myAppName
  services:
  - discovery
  - config-server
profile:
  dev:
    memory: 1024M
    instances: 1
  prod:
    memory: 4096M
    instances: 4
```

Assuming we will need to pass a parameter `profile=dev` to the `cf push` command is fine.

In DEV environment 1 instance with 1024M of memory will be deployed; while in PROD environments, 4 instances with 4096M of memory will be deployed.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you reconsider using variables in your manifest. You can use `--var-file`, but if you want to avoid having those files present you can just pass in multiple `--var=<name>=<val>` arguments instead.

That or just have `dev.yml` and `prod.yml` files, you can then `cf push -f dev.yml` or `cf push -f prod.yml` and pick between the two. There's a little duplication, but the files are tiny so it shouldn't be a big deal.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It should be `--var <name>=<val>` not `--var=<name>=<val>`

Comment: @person - Just tested with `cf version 6.48.0+ca3deaa94.2019-12-04` and both ways work.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think, trying to achieve everything using CF CLI commands is the right way to do

I would achieve this much simply by writing a bash script and executing cf-push sequencely in whichever fashion I would like to have..

Comment: I'm not sure why you are suggesting executing sequentially, I only want to deploy to one env (dev or prod) at a time.

Comment: Whatever... you can achieve by generating manifest file dynamically from a manifest-template and then push it using bash-scripts for dev / prod or to whatever setting you may prefer